# How to add the user input in the loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, addition

I'm using array and loop, at the first input the user must enter the number of subjects and use the number to be the size of the array. Then on the loop, the program will accept "grades" on each subject.

I need to add those grades.

Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaseStudy1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numsub, grade, sum, ave;
    System.out.print("\nEnter number of subjects: ");
        numsub = inp.nextInt();

    int num[]=new int [numsub];

    int y=0;

        for(int x=0;x<numsub;x++) {
            y=y+1;

            System.out.print("\nEnter Grade in Subject [" + y + "] : ");
            grade = inp.nextInt();

            num[x]=grade;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Java `=/=` JavaScript

Comment: What is it doing? what is it not doing? You're not giving us any details here.

Comment: could you please, clear your Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you alreday got a variable for sum, just add this

`sum+=grade;`

into your for-loop after

`num[x] = grade;`

Answer (score 0):

Include another variable called gradsum initialize with 0. Then add grade to gradsum while getting the grade values.

```
    int gradsum = 0;
    int y=0;
    for(int x=0;x<numsub;x++) {            
        y=y+1;
        System.out.print("\nEnter Grade in Subject [" + y + "] : ");
        grade = inp.nextInt();

        num[x]=grade;
        gradsum +=grade;
    }

   System.out.print(" Total of the Grade : "+gradsum );
   System.out.print(" Average : " + gradsum / numsub );
```

Comment: System.out.print(" Average : " + gradsum / numsub );